# Emacs-like navigation to beginning/end of sentence in text

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, emacs, navigation

I think it is a really big advantage of macOS over other operating systems that it supports a lot of Emacs navigating keyboard shortcuts out of the box. (<kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, you name it...)

One shortcut that I am really missing is the capacity to move to the beginning or end of a sentence in a text (in Emacs this is <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>). I could not find a substitute yet to emulate this behavior in macOS.

If someone would know a possibility how to do that I would be really happy!

Comment: By default, Control-A and Control-E do what you're looking for.  If I'm not mistaken, those are the default Emacs bindings.

Comment: No this the beginning or end of line, not sentence